# Round system RAM and HDD bytes, UP to nearest even gigabyte. Python

Tags: python, math, wmi, rounding

I'm collecting the system information of the current machine. Part of this information is the RAM and HDD capacity. Problem is that the capacity being gathered is measured in bytes rather than GB.

In a nutshell, how do I convert the display of the internal specifications to resemble what you would see from a consumer/commercial stand point?

1000GB HDD or 8GB RAM as opposed to the exact number of bytes available. Especially since manufacturers set aside different amounts of recovery sectors, RAM can be used for integrated graphics and the 1000 vs 1024 binary differential, etc... Here's an example of my current code:

```
import os
import wmi #import native powershell functionality
import math

c = wmi.WMI()  
SYSINFO = c.Win32_ComputerSystem()[0]    # Manufacturer/Model/Spec blob

RAMTOTAL = int(SYSINFO.TotalPhysicalMemory)        # Gathers only the RAM capacity in bytes.
RAMROUNDED = math.ceil(RAMTOTAL / 2000000000.) * 2.000000000        # attempts to round bytes to nearest, even, GB.
HDDTOTAL = int(HDDINFO.size) # Gathers only the HDD capacity in bytes.
HDDROUNDED = math.ceil(HDDTOTAL / 2000000000.) * 2.000000000        # attempts to round bytes to nearest, even, GB.
HDDPRNT = "HDD: " + str(HDDROUNDED) + "GB"
RAMPRNT = "RAM: " + str(RAMROUNDED) + "GB"
print(HDDPRNT)
print(RAMPRNT)
```

The area of interest is lines `8-11`where I'm rounding **up** to the nearest **even** number since the internal size of RAM/HDD are always lower than advertised for reasons mentioned previously. StackOverflow posts have gotten me this method which is the most accurate, across the most machines, but it's still hard coded. Meaning the HDD only rounds accurately for either hundreds of GB or thousands, not both. Also, the RAM isn't 100% accurate.

Here's a couple workarounds that come to mind that will produce the results I'm looking for:

- Adding additional commands to `RAMTOTAL` that may or may not be available. Allowing for GB output instead of KB. However. I would prefer it to be apart of the `WMI` import instead of straight native Windows code.
- Figure out a more static method of rounding. ie: `if HDDTOTAL > 1TB` round up to decimal point `X`. `else HDDTOTAL < 1TB` use different rounding method.

Comment: Does this need to be done in Python?  I can help you with PowerShell, if that is an option.

Comment: Yea. That's an option. I'd prefer it in format of the WMI import but more than willing to hear what you have for Powershell. I might be able to convert it to WMI later on.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I used a combination of the two previous suggestions.

I used an if loop, rather than a while loop, but get the same results. I also mirrored the same internal process of the suggested powershell commands to keep the script more native to python and without adding modules/dependencies.

```
GBasMB = int(1000000000) # Allows for accurate Bytes to GB conversion

global RAMSTRROUNDED
RAMTOTAL = int(SYSINFO.TotalPhysicalMemory) / (GBasMB) # Outputs GB by dividing by previous MB variable
RAMROUNDED = math.ceil(RAMTOTAL / 2.) * 2 # Rounds up to nearest even whole number
RAMSTRROUNDED = int(RAMROUNDED) # final converted variable

HDDTOTAL = int(HDDINFO.size) / (GBasMB) # Similar process as before for HardDrive
HDDROUNDED = math.ceil(HDDTOTAL / 2.) * 2 # round up to nearest even whole number

def ROUNDHDDTBORGB(): # function for determining TB or GB sized HDD
    global HDDTBORGBOUTPUT
    global HDDPRNT
    if HDDROUNDED >= 1000: # if equal to or greater than 1000GB, list as 1TB
        HDDTBORGB = HDDROUNDED * .001
        HDDTBORGBOUTPUT = str(HDDTBORGB) + "TB"
        HDDPRNT = "HDD: " + str(HDDTBORGBOUTPUT)
        print(HDDPRNT)
    elif HDDROUNDED < 1000: # if less than 1000GB list as GB
        HDDTBORGBOUTPUT = str(str(HDDROUNDED) + "GB")
        HDDPRNT = "HDD: " + str(HDDTBORGBOUTPUT)
```

I've ran this script on several dozen computers and seems to accurately gather the appropriate amount of RAM and HDD capacities. Regardless of how much RAM the integrated graphics decides to consume and/or reserve sectors on the HDD, etc...

Answer (score 1):

I think you could write a simple function that solves it. In case the number in kB would be significantly smaller or greater, I added a possibility of different suffixes (It is inspired by very similar example in a book Dive Into Python 3). It might look something like this:

```
def round(x):
    a = 0
    while x > 1000:
        suffixes = ('kB','MB','GB','TB')
        a += 1 #This will go up the suffixes tuple with each division
        x = x /1000
    return math.ceil(x), suffixes[a]
```

Results of this function might look like this:

```
>>> print(round(19276246))
(20, 'GB')
>>> print(round(135565666656))
(136, 'TB')
>>> print(round(1355))
(2, 'MB')
```

and you could implement it to your code like this:

```
import os
import wmi #import native powershell functionality
import math

def round(x):
    a = 0
    while x > 1000:
        suffixes = ('kB','MB','GB','TB')
        a += 1 #This will go up the suffixes tuple for each division
        x = x /1000
    return math.ceil(x), suffixes[a]

    .
    .
    .

RAMROUNDED = round(RAMTOTAL)       #attempts to round bytes to nearest, even, GB.
HDDTOTAL = int(HDDINFO.size) # Gathers only the HDD capacity in bytes.
HDDROUNDED = round(HDDTOTAL)        #attempts to round bytes to nearest, even, GB.
HDDPRNT = "HDD: " + str(HDDROUNDED[0]) + HDDROUNDED[1]
RAMPRNT = "RAM: " + str(RAMROUNDED[0]) + RAMROUNDED[1]
print(HDDPRNT)
print(RAMPRNT)
```

Comment: You're code only works/ouputs for MB. Something with the tuple I'm sure. I have limited experience with tuple but I see where you're going. Perhaps I can get the same effect using an array. Thanks for the input.

Comment: Wheter you use a tuple or a list (A sort of array in Python) for the suffixes shouldn't make a difference. The code should work. I can't really tell what's wrong as I don't see what values are you getting on your RAMTOTAL and HDDTOTAL variables.

Answer (score 0):

PowerShell has a lot of very powerful native math capabilities built in, allowing us to do things like divide by 1GB to get the whole number in gigabytes of a particular drive.

So, to see the total physical memory rounded by 1 GB, this is how to do it:

```
get-wmiobject -Class Win32_ComputerSystem | 
select @{Name='Ram(GB)';Expression={[int]($_.TotalPhysicalMemory /1GB)}}
```

This method is called a Calculated Property, the way it differs from using a regular select statement (like Select TotalPhysicalMemory) is that I'm telling PowerShell to make a new Prop call Ram(GB) and use the following expression to determine it's value.

```
[int]($_.TotalPhysicalMemory /1GB)
```

The expression I'm using begins in the parenthesis, where I'm getting the TotalPhysicalMemory (which returns as 17080483840).  I then divide by 1GB to give me 15.9074401855469.  Finally, I apply [int] to cast the whole thing as an integer that is to say, make it a whole number, rounding as appropriate.

Here is the output

```
>Ram(GB)
-------
 16
```

Comment: Before I intergrate this into Python I ran the command through Powershell. Although it works, it's rounding down sometimes. For instance I have 8GB installed but it outputs 7. I assume due to the fact that "7.2GB useable" in the internal specs. Anyway to get this line to round UP rather than simply to nearest whole number?

Comment: Are you still interested in this answer? I see someone else has a very solid python approach. If you'd like to know how to round up, I can still provide that though

Comment: FoxDeploy. I'm interested in either, as long as it works. I would prefer to keep the dependencies to a minimum i.e. Not having to import subprocess module for native PowerShell execution. So a more focused Python approach would be preferred but I'm open minded towards a solution.